# Issue in referencing Bind variable

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am trying to spool records from a table for latest month(available in audit_table) and the previous month.
I was fetching the necessary dates from the audit table and storing them in bind variables. And then running the spool with those dates.
But I am unable to reference the bind variables :v_curr_month_date and :v_prev_month_date while spooling(in the part *report body*).

Getting ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

How do I reference the bind variable outside the Begin...End Block?

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET HEADING ON
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET LINESIZE 8000
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET WRAP OFF
SET RECSEP OFF
SET CONCAT OFF
SET DOCUMENT OFF
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET COLSEP ','
SET TIMING OFF
SET ESCAPE ON
-- working variables
VARIABLE v_curr_month      VARCHAR2(7);
VARIABLE v_prev_month      VARCHAR2(7);
VARIABLE v_curr_month_date VARCHAR2(10);
VARIABLE v_prev_month_date VARCHAR2(10);

DEFINE ext=".csv"

-- ensure that the date format is in the expected format for the report
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY';

BEGIN
   select to_char(cut_off_date-1,'DD/MM/YYYY'), to_char(cut_off_date-1,'MONYYYY'), to_char(add_months(cut_off_date-1,-1),'DD/MM/YYYY'), to_char(add_months(cut_off_date-1,-1),'MONYYYY') into 
   :v_curr_month_date, :v_curr_month, :v_prev_month_date, :v_prev_month from audit_table where measure_group='MONTHLY_HR_REPORT';
END;
/

SPOOL C:\Users\Desktop\Report_extract.csv

-- report header
SELECT 'EVENT_DATE,V_ID,DESC1,DESC2,PREV_TOTAL,CURR_TOTAL'
FROM dual
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

-- report body
SELECT CURR_TAB.EVENT_DATE||','||CURR_TAB.V_ID||','||CURR_TAB.DESC1||','||CURR_TAB.DESC2||','||
       PREV_TOTAL||','||CURR_TOTAL
FROM
(SELECT EVENT_DATE, V_ID, DESC1, DESC2,SUM(CNT_VALUE) CURR_TOTAL
FROM TABLE1
WHERE EVENT_DATE = to_date(:v_curr_month_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')----this is causing error
GROUP BY EVENT_DATE, V_ID, DESC1, DESC2) CURR_TAB
JOIN
(SELECT EVENT_DATE, V_ID, DESC1, DESC2,SUM(CNT_VALUE) PREV_TOTAL
FROM TABLE1
WHERE EVENT_DATE = to_date(:v_prev_month_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')---this is causing error
GROUP BY EVENT_DATE, V_ID, DESC1, DESC2) PREV_TAB
ON CURR_TAB.V_ID = PREV_TAB.V_ID
ORDER BY CURR_TAB.V_ID;

SPOOL OFF
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: @JohnConde: Thanks! I would keep that in mind..

Comment: if you remove the spool commands, does the script work without getting that error?

Comment: What you've posted seems to work fine, run through SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer. If this is exactly what you are running, which client (and version) are you using, and what is the full error message and stack you get?

Comment: @AlexPoole: I am connecting sqlplus through unix shell script. I am getting the error as SP2-0552: Bind variable "V_PREV_MONTH_DATE" not declared.

Comment: That isn't the message you said you got before. I've copied the code from your question into a .sql file and run that from SQL\*Plus, after creating dummy tables to match your queries. I don't get either error. That bind variable is, clearly, defined. Are you sure you are actually running the whole things as a single script, exactly as it appears in the question?